# Relations and set theory

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

Here is a question where I have to prove if this relation is a equivalence relation or not? I also have to provide necessary proof for the same. I present to you my question and my solution.

% is a relation on the set of all subsets of N, A%B iff
 $$A\div B $$ is a finite set. We need to determine if % is an equivalence relation or not?

Reflexive relation:

$$A R A$$
$$as\ (A \div A) = (A \bigcup A) -(A \bigcap A) = \{\} $$
and I considered null set as a finite set, I know this could be a mathematical disaster, but my instructor gave me this hint and I hope i haven't misinterpreted him.

Symmetric relation:

$$A R B \implies BRA$$
$$A \div B \implies B \div A$$
$$ \{ \Bbb N \} \implies \{\Bbb N\} $$
And similar for transitive relation.
I was a bit confused with his hint, please correct me for any wrong doing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'll show you how to prove symmetry, and hopefully that will show you how to approach transtivity yourself.  Suppose we have $A$%$B$. Then that means that $A\cup B$ - $A \cap B $ is a finite set $D$.  But since $B \cup A = A \cup B$ and $B \cap A = A \cap B$, we have that $B \cup A - A \cap B=D$, and is therefore finite as well. Hence, whenever $A$%$B$, we have $B$%$A$, and hence $R$ is symmetric.

HINT for transitivity: draw a Venn diagram!

Comment: Thanks so similarly for transitivity ARB  & BRC -> CRA. $$ (A U B) - (A intersection B) & (B U C) - (C intersection B) => (C U A) - (A intersection C). $$ Finite set D  = Finite set E, is that close to what you expected from me?

Comment: @PrathikGurudatt Transitivity is ARB & BRC -> ARC.  So you need to prove (or disprove) that if $A \cup B - A \cap B =$ finite $D$, and if $B \cup C - B \cap C= $ finite $E$, then $A \cup C - A \cap C=$ finnite set $F$... Do you think that is true?